# Resizing a box to zero height

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a box in this jsfiddle  -http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/myh7n/ - that I've set up with ordinary resize handles.

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').resizable({handles : 'n,e,s,w'});
});
```

I'd like to have the box become a horizontal line, now, by resizing it vertically to as small a height as possible, but the minimum seems to be about 13px. I've tried changing the offset of the resize handles but that doesn't seem to help. Does anyone know how I can resize the box down to height of 0, so I just have 2px line made from the borders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom [minHeight](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minHeight).

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').resizable({handles : 'n,e,s,w', minHeight: 0});
});
```

[A working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myh7n/2/)

[For further reading about the Resizable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/)